How to select rows that don't have overlapping dates
I have a table that contains dates for different products.  Each row on this table represents a ticket/issue and the start and end date for the tickets.  Each product can have multiple tickets, and the dates can overlap as seen below.
The question I'm trying to answer is, "Was there a ticket for a given day?".  I thought this would be most easily done by trying to select rows so that the dates don't overlap, but I'm unsure how to do this.
Here is an example of what it starts as.



id
start_date
end_date
product_id




128981
10/8/2024
10/12/2024
756


125654
10/9/2024
10/9/2024
756


129034
10/12/2024
10/15/2024
756


127171
10/13/2024
10/13/2024
756


127796
10/15/2024
10/15/2024
756



And this is what I would like to have selected.



id
start_date
end_date
product_id




128981
10/8/2024
10/12/2024
756


129034
10/12/2024
10/15/2024
756



How would I be able to construct a select query to do this?

This problem you are trying to solve "Was there a ticket for a given day?" is called Islands and Gaps and we already have tons of answers here. Here is one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838025/find-gap-between-values-of-the-same-type-in-sql buckle up it is not a simple solution.

@JorgeCampos I appreciate the information!  This is an entirely new problem to me, I will dig in to the problem (now that I know the name that's super helpful) and the link you provided.

The old thread that @Jorge Campos shared is indeed helpful as your 1st focus is to identify and group overlapping ranges then you try to select the minimum start date and maximum end date of each continuous range within each product_id.
I used a CTE  to group overlapping rows and check if the start_date of the current row is within the end_date of the previous row for the same product_id if not, it starts a new group.
WITH DateRanges AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        product_id,
        -- Create a group for each continuous date range
        SUM(CASE WHEN start_date <= LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY start_date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY start_date) AS range_group
    FROM 
        tickets
),
AggregatedRanges AS (
    SELECT 
        MIN(id) AS id,
        MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
        MAX(end_date) AS end_date,
        product_id
    FROM 
        DateRanges
    GROUP BY 
        product_id, range_group
)
SELECT * 
FROM AggregatedRanges
ORDER BY product_id, start_date

